# Evaluate $I=\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x)\cos(x)\cos(2x)\cos(4x)\cdots \cos(2^{n-1}x) \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Evaluate
>   $$I=\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(x)\cos(x)\cos(2x)\cos(4x)\dots \cos(2^{n-1}x) \mathrm dx$$

Now, I was thinking to start using the following property

$$\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \mathrm dx = \displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} f(a+b-x) \mathrm dx$$

Then I got here

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(0+\pi-x)\cos(0+\pi-x)\cos(2(0+\pi-x)) \dots  \cos(2^{n-1}(0+\pi-x)) \mathrm dx$$

and after a few steps I've reached to something that looks like the original integral. So, the answer that I got is $I=0$. Is this correct? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the fact that,

$$\cos (x )\cos(2x)\cos(4x)\cdots\cos(2^{n-1}x) = \frac{\sin(2^nx)}{2^n\sin(x)} $$

We have, $$\sin(x)\cos (x )\cos(2x)\cos(4x)\cdots\cos(2^{n-1}x) = \frac{\sin(2^nx)}{2^n}$$

So, $$I = \frac1{2^n}\int^\pi_0\sin(2^nx) = \frac1{2^n} \int^\pi_0\sin(2^n\pi-2^nx) = - \frac1{2^n}\int^\pi_0\sin(2^nx) = -I$$

$$\Rightarrow2I = 0 \Rightarrow I = 0$$

Answer (score 6):

Hint:  $$\sin x \cos x = \frac{1}{2} \sin 2x \\ \sin 2x \cos 2x = \frac{1}{2} \sin 4x \\ \vdots $$

Comment: Thank you ! So, the answer should be 0 , right ?

Comment: @JohnOmielan LOL this is what I get for answering math questions at 2 AM

Answer (score 2):

There are $n$ cosine factors in the integrand, but let's not forget the $n=0$ case:$$\begin{align}\sin x\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\cos2^{j}x&=\sin x\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{\sin2^{j+1}x}{2\sin2^{j}x}\\&=\frac{\sin2^{n}x}{2^{n}}\\\implies\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin x\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\cos2^{j}xdx&=\left[\frac{-\cos2^{n}x}{4^{n}}\right]_{0}^{\pi}\\&=2\delta_{n0}.\end{align}$$